# How can I check if a type is a subtype of a type in Python?

Tags: python

How can I check if a type is a subtype of a type in Python?  I am not referring to instances of a type, but comparing type instances themselves.  For example:

```
class A(object):
    ...

class B(A):
    ...

class C(object)
    ...

# Check that instance is a subclass instance:
isinstance(A(), A) --> True
isinstance(B(), A) --> True
isinstance(C(), A) --> False

# What about comparing the types directly?
SOME_FUNCTION(A, A) --> True
SOME_FUNCTION(B, A) --> True
SOME_FUNCTION(C, A) --> False
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Maybe [`issubclass`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#issubclass)?

```
>>> class A(object): pass
>>> class B(A): pass
>>> class C(object): pass
>>> issubclass(A, A)
True
>>> issubclass(B, A)
True
>>> issubclass(C, A)
False
```

Comment: what about in cases where some but not all arguments are types? Eg, in comprehensions to filter out error types interpreted as missing values? eg `[x for x in [1,2,TypeError,4] if issubclass(x,Exception)]` throws `arg 1 must be a class`. This seems to work when in conjunction with the above: `not isinstance(x,type)` but is there a cleaner approach?

Comment: @alancalvitti How about `[x for x in [1,2,TypeError,4] if isinstance(x,type) and issubclass(x,Exception)]` ?

Comment: @alancalvitti because `issubclass`'s first argument must always be a type. You an re-write it using `isinstance` check `[x for x in [1, 2, TypeError(), 4] if isinstance(x, Exception)]` or `[x for x in [1,2,TypeError,4] if issubclass(type(x),Exception)]`