# python runtime type checking

Tags: python, python-3.5, mypy

I would like to check the type compatibility between the output of one function and the input of another. I know mypy does static type checking but I couldn't find anything on running it from python. Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
from typing import Union, Callable
import inspect


def gt_4(num: Union[int, float]) -> bool:
    return num > 4


def add_2(num: Union[int, float]) -> float:
    return num + 2.0


def types_are_compatible(type1, type2):
    """ return True if types are compatible, else False """
    # how to do this in a clean way? 
    # some kind of MyPy API would be nice here to not reinvent the wheel

# get annotations for output of func1 and input of func2
out_annotation = inspect.signature(gt_4).return_annotation
in_annotation = inspect.signature(add_2).parameters.get('num').annotation

# check if types are compatible, 
types_are_compatible(out_annotation, in_annotation)
```

I found a small github project called [typegaurd](https://github.com/agronholm/typeguard) that seems to do something similar but I am really reluctant to use a small 3rd party library for the code I am working on. What is the cleanest way to do this? Is there anything built in to the standard library or MyPy that I can just use directly?

Comment: Isn't this just a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/15892237/4714742? Or is there a reason you can't just use `issubclass`?

Comment: So types_are_compatible just needs to return issubclass(type1, type2) ? I ran a few tests and it seems to work. I had no idea the classes from the typing module worked this way. Are there any edge cases where this might not work?

Comment: I think it would do `return issubclass(type1, type2) or issubclass(type2, type1)` so it would go either way, like `types_are_compatible(Union[int,float], int)` should return True but `int` is the one that is a subclass.

Comment: It seems that it should be only `return issubclass(type1, type2)`. For example, `issubclass(int, Union[int, float])` should return True because the second function can accept an int, but the reverse should be False because the first function cannot accept a float.

Comment: right... nevermind then.  so yes, you'd just do `types_are_compatible = issubclass` or just use `issubclass` directly instead of the alias.

Comment: This doesnt seem to work as expected for some of the types. For example, `issubclass(List[int], Sequence[int])` returns False, shouldn't that return True? I am no longer sure that issubclass is a sound solution to the problem.